# generic way to evaluate a function cost at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, iterator, constexpr

I am currently working on the implementation of a multidimensional array iterator. Considering the iteration over two contiguous ranges (for std::equal, std::copy purposes) that represent compatible data with different alignements (row vs col major in 2D), I would like to find the stride order for each iterator giving the fastest execution time.

For example:

```
row of vector components = A -> m elements
row of vectors =           B -> n elements
2D plan of vectors =       C -> 3 elements
row of plan of vectors =   D -> 10 elements

given the datas ordered by ascending strides:
first array:   B | A | C | D
second array:  B | A | D | C

 Obviously, we can iterate over both iterators by bunches of m*n elements. Then:

 If we choose the first array convention, the first iterator is contiguous and the second one 
 will perform (3 - 1)*(10 - 1) jumps forward with a stride of 10 and (10 - 1) jumps backward.

 If we choose the second array convention, the second iterator is contiguous and the first one will 
 perform (10 - 1)*(3 - 1) jumps forward with a stride of 3 and (3 - 1) jumps backward.

=> The second convention is better at everything in this example.
```

Since I have to take a lot of factors to take into account like the memory back and forth, the contiguity and the iterator implementation itself (which is not trivial), I want to perform an experimental plan. But I also know everything at compile time (the sizes and the strides) so it would be cool to perform the experimental plan at compile time for each template instantiation. My question is:

Is it possible to evaluate the runtime cost of some instructions at compile time, when everything is known at compile time except the memory address of the input array ?

Comment: Can you provide example code?

Comment: I can't, because the implementation would depend on the answer. Basically, I just want to say: std::copy(a.beginWith<decltype(b)>(), a.endWith<decltype(b)>(), b.beginWith<decltype(a)>())

Comment: As long as instructions runtime cost is sufficiently reproductible it is possible. The sure way is to evaluate it at runtime, deduce a mathematical law (which could be a dumb look-up table) and then use that law at compile time.

Comment: @Oliv: I could take your proposition seriously, thank you ! If you post an answer with a possible systematic approach, I will give you my bounty. It would be even better to find a pre build step that fit macro replacements of an external test program output.

Comment: @Cevik Honestly, the first step would be to find the pertinent/ limiting factor, then I would have to find a mathematical law that could be a good fit, then code it in for exemple cmake/C++, as a configuration step... I used to be pay a lot for that! I send you a report 1K$ the page.

Comment: @Oliv: Haha this is indeed a real task and I don't ask you to do it for me. By "systematic approach", I was talking about a stack overflow like response, general and useful like a cook recipe, not an in depth inspection of this array example. But I suspect you to be a veteran of this kind of tasks, hence the confusion !

Comment: Actualy I am a physicist, and the method I propose you is just the heart of my job: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method. I have never used it to study specificaly a computer as a physical object. But I suppose it is a pertinent approach since computer behavior is getting too complex for theorician.

Comment: what you are asking, is basically to ask the compiler what is the best of two functions, in term of optimization, and choose that one, right?. If that is the case, I would point out that in general this is the other way around: you design your algos, so that they can run with the computational complexity you designed.

Comment: @crsn: That's what i am asking indeed. Most of the time, designing an algorithm is not a problem when working at a higher level. In this case, it is more like a compiler low level implementation which might one day appear built in the std::multiarray or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Your question is based on bad assumptions.

Some of the bad assumptions (there might be others):

- The function is used as it is: The compiler might inline it in many places or decide you are better-off having it in a separate function because the code size improves. Since you can get slightly different behavior by the surrounding code you might see different performance.
- There is a cost for an instructions: Processors run instructions out of order in many cases or they parallelize instructions. Something that might take a long time like a division might be hidden if it's surrounded by other memory access and gets it's costs amortized.
- Performance is independent of the processor. The compiler doesn't know which specific processor you're going to run on, how big the caches or the cache lines are, how fast the main memory is or how good/bad branch prediction will be. All these have a huge impact on performance.

What you can do is profile and measure. Profile the application using this function and see if you actually need to fix it. Measure the performance you're getting and experiment with the different options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, knowing that the compiler is able to decide what to do before the run-time, it should be able to decide between several versions, pick one randomly in the equivalent cases, even each time the call is made if necessary.

Comment: I am just saying that there is something to do above the usual consensus of measuring everything, now that the constexpr instructions are well supported. Actually, I am going implement an iterator with a counter, following the for loops involved, the index count... a painful tentative to emulate what gcc is doing naturally. Maybe someone could find a hack to involve two constructors and let the compiler make an ellision of the heavier ? I don't know, this is black magic :)

Comment: @Cevik Take a benchmark comparing linear and binary search. The linear search is faster on short sets. The exact point where binary search becomes faster depends on the system (cache, speed, memory, etc). The benchmark is a binary program, already compiled, frozen if you will. Even though there's no change to the generated code you still get different results on different systems. What you are asking is for the compiler to pick the right option for all situations, which is not possible in the general case.

Comment: I understand your point concerning the critical point, but a simple example like the loop unrolling shows that the compiler is able to decide following -O3 options and so on. Even if the compiler is not right every time, that's a default behavior that we don't optimize most of the time.

Comment: Actually, this problem reminds me the incompleteness theorem and the halting problem, which hints me that maybe there is no general way to evaluate the function cost at the compile time.

Comment: @K.R.Park thanks for sharing the halting problem perspective. I think that we could be more restrictive about the "general way" => no conditional branches, just like when doing kernel cuda calls avoiding branch divergence.